# I want my button to change the Status set, but instead of changing it, goes to a href page instead

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

First off: There are no YouTube videos or tutorials for this as far as I know. I found some but they were JavaScript, but I have no knowledge of it so I can't do it in a very short time.

I recently posted the same question but altered my codes after some people's suggestions. I got a lot of errors instead of a solution...

Anyway, I have a picture of my site and what I want to do.

Site:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/znRin.jpg

and here's a picture of what I want to do:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTSxV.jpg

And finally my codes are below, I cut down the HTML parts which isn't really necessary.

adduser.php:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
        {
            header('location: login.php');
        die();
        }


    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Manage users</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="image/favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="image/favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/table.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include ("header.php"); ?>

    <?php 

    require ("config.php");

    ?>


    <form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="adduser.php">
    <div class="table-container">
        <div class="table-something">
            <div class="table-header">
                <span id="message"></span>
                <h2>Admin List<span class="blink">_</span> </h2>
                <input name="var1" type="text" id="var1" />
                <input class="dede" type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
            </div>
        <div class="table-body">
            <table class="table-hen">

    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['var1'])) {
    $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
    }
    else {
        $var1 = 1;
    }

    $sql= "SELECT user_id, fname, mname, lname, username, type, a_e_num, user_status FROM users WHERE a_e_num LIKE :search";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':search', '%' . $var1 . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        ?>
        <tr>
                    <th>User Id</th>
                    <th>Name </th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Employee # </th>
                    <th>User Type</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result as $row): 

        ?>


                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['fname']; ?>  <?php echo $row['mname']; ?> <?php echo $row['lname']; ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['a_e_num']; ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>

                    <td>
                        <?php if ($row['user_status']=='Enable') echo "Active"; 
                        if ($row['user_status']=='Disable') echo "Disabled" ?>
                        </td>
                    <td>
                    <?php
                    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
                    $status = '';
                    if ($row['user_status'] == 'Enable') {
                        $status = 'Enable';
                    }
                    else if ($row['user_status'] == 'Disable') {
                        $status = 'Disable';
                    } 
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
                    $status = $row['user_status'];
                    ?>
                        <a class="archive" action="archive.php" onclick="
                        return confirm('Are you sure you want to <?php if ($row['user_status']=='Enable') echo "disable"; 
                        if ($row['user_status']=='Disable') echo "enable"?> this user account?')" 
                        href="archive.php?user_id=<?= $user_id?>&status=<?=$status?>">

                        <?php if ($row['user_status']=='Disable')   
                        echo "Unarchive"; 
                        if ($row['user_status']=='Enable') 
                            echo "Archive" ?>

                            </a></td>
                </tr>

    <?php endforeach; 
    } else {
    echo 'there is nothing to show';
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <br><h1></h1>
    <br><h1></h1>
    <br><h1></h1>
    <br><h1></h1>
    <br><h1></h1>

        <?php include ("footer.php"); ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

And here's my Archive.php:

```
    <?php
    require ("config.php");

    $user_id= $_GET['user_id'];
    $user_status = $_GET['user_id'];

    $query = $db->prepare ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id, user_status = :user_status");

    $query->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
    $query->bindParam(':user_status',$user_status);
    $query->execute();

    if ($user_status=='Enable')
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_status = 'Disable' WHERE user_id = :user_id";
    }
    if ($user_status=='Disable')
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_status='Enable' WHERE user_id = :user_id";
    }

    if ($query->execute([':user_status'=>$user_status, ':user_id'=>$user_id])){

        header("Location:adduser.php");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, you need to update the user status without refreshing the web page? then you will **MUST** have go with ajax/javascript

Comment: Complete your html code please and answer to @hassan question...

Comment: I just want to change the Status to Disabled or Enabled after the user clicks the button without using Js or Ajax.

Comment: I updated my complete html code and made a clearer title. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to clear your statement and separate your parameters like below.

**Step 1:**

Parameters are (Query String) which start with `?` and more paramters will be followed by `&`

```
<?php
$user_id = $row['user_id'];
$status = '';
if ($row['user_status'] == 'Enable') {
    $status = 'Enable';
} else if ($row['user_status'] == 'Disable') {
    $status = 'Disable';
}
?>
<a href="archive.php?user_id=<?=$user_id?>&user_status=<?=$status?>">
```

IF your `$row['user_status']` value is always same as conditional statement then you don't need condition simply follow assign variable.

```
<?php
$user_id = $row['user_id'];
$status = $row['user_status'];
?>
<a href="archive.php?user_id=<?=$user_id?>&status=<?=$status?>">
```

**Step 2:**
Then this

```
$id= $_GET['user_id'];
```

To

```
$user_id= $_GET['user_id'];
$user_status = $_GET['user_status'];
```

because your bind parameters take variable which is not defined in your `Archive.php`

```
$query->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$query->bindParam(':user_status',$user_status);
```

EDIT 2:

change your ` where it start with

```
<td>
<?php
$user_id = $row['user_id'];
$status = $row['user_status'];
```

Just replace with below.

```
<td>
    <?php
    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $status = $row['user_status'];
    $btn_confirm = '';
    if ($status == 'Enable') {
        $btn_confirm = "disable";
    } else if ($status == 'Disable') {
        $btn_confirm = "enable";
    }
    ?>
    <a class="archive" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to <?= $btn_confirm; ?> this user account?')"
       href="Archive.php?user_id=<?= $user_id ?>&status=<?= $status ?>">
        <?php if ($status == 'Disable') {
            echo "Unarchive";
        } else if ($status == 'Enable') {
            echo "Archive"; }
        ?>

    </a>
</td>
```

> Note: your file name is `Archive.php` not `archive.php` this causing issue for blank page

Comment: I replaced everything you said but it does not update my user_status to Disable or Enable, instead, it still goes to the blank page named
localhost/sample2/archive.php?user_id=2&status=Enable

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: sorry my mistake this should be `$user_status = $_GET['user_status'];`

Comment: I got an error instead called Undefined index: user_status on the same line where I put it.

Comment: compare edit code with your code. i've changed now anchor tag `<a href="archive.php?user_id=<?=$user_id?>&user_status=<?=$status?>">`

Comment: Edited it, thanks for your quick response!
However, it is still the same with the first problem, it goes to the blank page and does not edit the status table.

Comment: check your query if your record is update or not? and then add `exit();` below this line `header("Location:adduser.php");`, previously your code was not correct it is not correct and there is only one issue which is adding `exit()` after every `header()` redirection

Comment: Added exit(); and it still goes there. I'm thinking my UPDATE query on archive.php is to blame here, or if not, do I have to include ("adduser.php") on archive.php?

I'm not sure, but I'll screenshot my latest codes as I might've wrote something wrong.

Huge thanks for helping btw!

https://imgur.com/a/LYwkh

Comment: see edit 2. replace <td> with mine and check your code.